# Final URL - PHP (Effective URL) How to

Tags: php

I apologize in advance for my English.
I need from a url http://www.streamuj.tv/video/2f15014c90a9f62af511?streamuj=hd&authorize=7736cdf0f3719ed75b26132aee184525 get the final redirected to url redirection (.flv) url.

I tried this, but somehow it doesn't get the info I need:

```
<?php

function getMainUrl($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
    return $headers['Location'];
}

echo getMainUrl("http://www.streamuj.tv/video/2f15014c90a9f62af511?streamuj=hd&authorize=7736cdf0f3719ed75b26132aee184525");

?>
```

When use:

> http://getlinkinfo.com/info?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.streamuj.tv%2Fvideo%2F2f15014c90a9f62af511%3Fstreamuj%3Dhd%26authorize%3D7736cdf0f3719ed75b26132aee184525+&x=45&y=6

it redirects to:

> http://s14.streamuj.tv:8080/vid/8f18cade6df7fc2d54a3522e7515771e/58a1ecfa/2f15014c90a9f62af511_hd.flv?start=0
>   and this is the one I need from php

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using cURL, we tell it only to fetch the header and to follow redirects.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.streamuj.tv/video/2f15014c90a9f62af511?streamuj=hd&authorize=7736cdf0f3719ed75b26132aee184525');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$header = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print_r($info);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://s14.streamuj.tv:8080/vid/c7194f1279591f88c162382a0a5a49d1/58a1f0a5/2f15014c90a9f62af511_hd.flv?start=0
    [content_type] => video/x-flv
    ...
)
```

Comment: This does not handle more than 1 redirect :( try it on google.com, you have 2, http -> https and naked to www.

Comment: @Djongov Are you sure? It should handle endless number of redirects as far as I know.

Comment: Yea, pretty sure. I am doing a security headers inspection and it stumbles on the first redirect and my http response status is 301/302

Answer (score 0):

This Work:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$proxy = array("88.159.43.160:80");
$proxyNum = 0;
$proxy = explode(':', $proxy[$proxyNum]);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.streamuj.tv/video/2f15014c90a9f62af511?streamuj=hd&authorize=7736cdf0f3719ed75b26132aee184525');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);
$header = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print_r($info);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [url] => http://s14.streamuj.tv:8080/vid/0b9ac442e33b2f0fe72dd45295b6e7bd/58a1f3b0/2f15014c90a9f62af511_hd.flv?start=0 [content_type] => video/x-flv [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 738 [request_size] => 326 [filetime] => 1481886073 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 1 [total_time] => 3.485 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 3.063 [pretransfer_time] => 3.063 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 674855667 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 3.188 [redirect_time] => 0.297 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 88.159.43.160 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 80 [local_ip] => 192.168.0.8 [local_port] => 57532 )
```

How to can please echo only this: http://s14.streamuj.tv:8080/vid/0b9ac442e33b2f0fe72dd45295b6e7bd/58a1f3b0/2f15014c90a9f62af511_hd.flv?start=0 
?

Comment: `echo $info['url'];`

Comment: You're welcome. You should thank to OptimusCrime actually :) It's his solution.

Comment: Don't deface your own answer. You need to read [ask] and [answer].